# If $\dim W < \dim V$ then $U(T)$ is is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over the field $F$, so that $\dim W < \dim V$. Let $T$ be a linear transformation $V \to W$ and let $U$ be a linear transformation $W \to V$. Then the transformation $UT$, which is the composition of $U$ and $T$ is not invertible.

Proof:

Suppose $\dim V = n$ and $\dim W = m$. Let $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ be a basis for $V$, then, since $m<n$, we have that $T(\alpha_1), \dots, T(\alpha_n)$ are linearly dependent. Thus,
$$
x_1 T(\alpha_1) + \dots + x_nT(\alpha_n) = 0
$$

in which not all $x_i=0$. It then means,
$$
x_1\alpha_1 + \dots + x_n\alpha_n \neq 0.
$$

Consider now,
\begin{align}
UT(x_1\alpha_1 + \dots + x_n\alpha_n)
&= U(T(x_1\alpha_1) + \dots + T(x_n\alpha_n)) \\
&= U(x_1T(\alpha_1) + \dots + x_nT(\alpha_n)) \\
&= U(0) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

From this, $UT$ is singular, since there is a non-zero vector in the null space. Therefore, it is not invertable.

Is this proof valid ?

Comment: To quote the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should use proof verification instead, right ?

Comment: [tag:proof-verification] just redirects to [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/synonyms). So it's not any better.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Comment: The transformation will have a non-trivial nullspace and so cannot be injective, therefore it's not a bijection and thus not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof seems fine to me. It could be condensed slightly as follows:

We have $\text{rank}(T) \le \dim W$ so by the rank-nullity theorem, $\text{nullity}(T) = \dim V - \text{rank}(T) \ge \dim V - \dim W > 0$. This means there is a nonzero element $v$ such that $UTv = U(Tv)=U0=0$, so $UT$ cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks correct to me. You can also prove as follows.

Suppose, for a contradiction, that $U\circ T$ is invertible. Then
$$U\circ T \  \text{invertible}\implies U\circ T \ \text{injective}\implies T \ \text{injective},$$
which is a contradiction, because $T:V\to W$ and $\dim W<\dim V$ (a linear transformation to a smaller dimensional space can not be injective).

Another similar proof is as follows.

Suppose, for a contradiction, that $U\circ T$ is invertible. Then
$$U\circ T \  \text{invertible}\implies U\circ T \ \text{surjective}\implies U \ \text{surjective},$$
which is a contradiction, because $U:W\to V$ and $\dim W<\dim V$ (a linear transformation to a larger dimensional space can not be surjective).